# SharePoint Config Log grew massively

Tags: database

We have a Hyper V machine hosting our SharePoint server. We are currently in the process of moving our site off the Virtual machine, for example, A, onto our server B. Because I have been busy with other work I haven't been playing around with the SharePoint site on our server A at all and the Config log has grown to 52GB.

So in the past 2 weeks no extra data or information has been added to the site. There has been no activity at all on the site and this Config log is 52Gb.

I am  fairly new at share point so I don't have much of an understanding about why this has happened. Any help with me much appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a test/dev farm try to run this script at SQL

```
use sharepoint_config
go
alter database sharepoint_config set recovery simple
go
dbcc shrinkfile('SharePoint_Config_log',100)
go
alter database sharepoint_config set recovery FUll
go
```

**Note :** 
The shrink operation will effect on the SQL Server Performance.therefore, I recommend before go live you should prepare `a LOG_BACKUP Maintenance Plan` to backup the log file frequently to avoid the shrink operation on production.

For more details check [The transaction log for database ‘SharePoint_Config’ is full](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/26/the-transaction-log-for-database-sharepoint_config-is-full-due-to-log_backup/)

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix this is in SQL server:

USE MTP_RC_DB; -- Connect to the database that you want to shrink

ALTER DATABASE MTP_RC_DB SET RECOVERY SIMPLE; -- Set the recovery model to SIMPLE

CHECKPOINT; -- Issue a CHECKPOINT to purge out the inactive transactions

DBCC SHRINKFILE (MTP_RC_DB_LOG, 5); -- Shrink the transaction log file to a reasonable size

ALTER DATABASE MTP_RC_DB SET RECOVERY FULL; -- Set the recovery model back to FULL

The reason is that the recovery model on that database is set to full instead of simple, so every transaction is saved on the log so you will have full recovery at any point in time.
Here you can find that Microsoft itself, recommends to switch that database to simple recovery model.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678868.aspx